# How to fillter data from result of sql query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a sql query

```
SELECT MenuID,
       Text,
       ParentID,
       Refcode  
FROM Menu E1 
WHERE E1.RefCode IN (0,50,51,60,63,57)
```

It will produce   result set

```
MenuID      Text                                               ParentID    Refcode
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------
1           Product                                            NULL        0         
2           Applications                                       NULL        0         
3           Document                                           NULL        0         
4           Support                                            NULL        0         
6           Background                                         1           0         
7           Details                                            1           50        
8           Mobile Device                                      2           51        
12          Performance Tests                                  2           0         
15          FAQ                                                4           57        
18          InternetRestrictions                               6           60        
21          Modem Results                                      12          63
```

I need another query which reduce the result , ie **i need to remove all the items which hasn't any child**   so in the expected results, the item with menuid 3 must be remove because it has no any child, how i can achieve this result set using another query on the result of first query or changing first query

Comment: Which flavour of SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Menuid, 
       Text, 
       Parentid, 
       Refcode 
FROM   Menu E1 
WHERE  E1.Refcode IN ( 0, 50, 51, 60, 63, 57 ) 
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Menu E2
    WHERE E2.Parentid = E1.Menuid
)
```

[**Sql-Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1a8d/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use a join with distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  E1.Menuid, 
  E1.Text, 
  E1.Parentid, 
  E1.Refcode 
FROM Menu E1
JOIN Menu E2 ON E2.Parentid = E1.Menuid
WHERE E1.Refcode IN ( 0, 50, 51, 60, 63, 57 )
```